# How to convert my dataframe to a 2d list with all column as a list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df,

```
Name  Class
Sri   A
Ram   B
```

My expected output is

```
 [["Name","Sri","Ram"],["Class","A","B"]]
```

I tried `df.values.tolist()` but gives row wise lists, I need it in column wise. Thanks in advance

Comment: Take the transpose of the dataframe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `transpose`:

```
print (df.values.T.tolist())
[['Sri', 'Ram'], ['A', 'B']]
```

If need also columns names first transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.T.reset_index().values.tolist())
[['Name', 'Sri', 'Ram'], ['Class', 'A', 'B']]
```

EDIT: For remove `NaN`s use list comprehension:

```
print (df)
  Name Class
0  Sri     A
1  Ram   NaN

L = df.values.T.tolist()
print (L)
[['Sri', 'Ram'], ['A', nan]]

L1 = [[i for i in x if pd.notnull(i)] for x in L]
print (L1)
[['Sri', 'Ram'], ['A']]
```